# Google Chrome doesn't delete my browsing history correctly

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, history

I have deleted everything that I could from my browser history:

```
chrome://settings/clearBrowserData
```

I checked everything and select `the begining of time`

Then when I access browsing history:

```
chrome://history/
```

There is nothing (as I expected), or to be precise `No history entries found.`

The problem is that I still see my specific search url with very specific query I have made a month ago, when I start typing the url of the website into chrome address bar.

How is that possible? Where is Google stroing these data. How to get rid off them completely?

I want to mention that my autosuggestion options look like this:

[image]

**So, what else should I delete to remove everything from autosuggestions?**

Right now it has some specific URLs (subpages, pages with very specific search query I have made in a month or so).

I have tried restarting Chrome and restarting my computer, but the urls are still in the autosuggestion.

Also I am unable to turn off the autosuggestion, even I have unchecked that option in settings.

My Google Chrome version is: **Version 27.0.1453.116 m** (probably the latest)

Btw. in Firefox deleting the history works as expected. So, I guess that this has nothing to do with the operating system I am using (Windows 7), but only it's an issue with Chrome itself.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem I couldn't replicate. I cleared all my browsing history since the beginning of time, and Google Chrome doesn't show any of my previous URLs.

However, you could be having an issue with [Google Web History](https://accounts.google.com/Login?service=hist).

[image]

You may have to go in and clear your history there. You also probably want to turn it off, it gets pretty annoying.

If that doesn't work, you probably have malware.

Comment: My `https://history.google.com/history/delete?hl=en&btnD` is empty too but it doesn't effect anything ;( . Also, I don't understand why Google Chrome is always autosuggesting even I have turned it off.

Comment: I tried to use CCleaner, it doesn't help either ;(

Comment: Did you try MalwareBytes? You get one free scan, and it once solved a problem I had with text in Firefox hyperlinking to random sites.

Comment: I have malwarebytes, nod32, spybot but everything is ok. I don't think it's a virus. The links are to normal sites and are specific e.g. to where I make comments, my specific query etc. I was thinking that I will re-install Chrome, but reinstalling chrome every time I want to delete urls seems weird.

Comment: The malware is called Chrome, its one of big G's primary spytools.

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect your Google account in Chrome's Settings

[image: Disconnect Google account]

Exit Google Chrome.

Re-start Google Chrome and sign in again using your Google account.

Having cleared the settings, Google Chrome will still automatically suggest search terms based on popular queries, but does not take your past browsing history into account.

[image: Chrome Omnibox]

### Clean Uninstall

To completely remove Chrome from Windows, uninstall Google Chrome from `Add or Remove Programs`.

Then proceed to delete the following folders

- %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome
- %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome SxS
- %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium

Re-install Google Chrome again.

Comment: I have tried this already, but without success ;(

Comment: @Derfder do you mean the autocomplete still works, similar to my 2nd screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

THIS WORKS

1. Close Google Chrome
2. Go to --->
   C:\Users\'Username'\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
3. Delete folder called 'Default'
   (WARNING : This will delete all history and chrome data.)
4. Restart Chrome
5. Try deleting History.
6. Say Like here if it worked.

Peace.

Answer (score 0):

To delete your specific URL links in Google Chrome address bar, hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and press <kbd>DELETE</kbd> on the selected URL.

You can only delete URLs where it shows a blank paper icon on the left side. Any other icons, such as a star or a magnifying glass, will not be deleted. Search criteria matching whatever you typed in the address bar will also not be deleted through this method.

Try experimenting around!

Answer (score -1):

**WHY IT DOESN'T WORK**

The history clear option only clears your browsing history on that particular device.

**DO THIS**

If you have signed into your Google account on another device, the history need to be cleared on that particular device.

Eg. If you clear your browsing history on your desktop PC, but not from your mobile device, then your browsing history from your mobile device will still remain within Google history (and maybe visible on any other web device).

Good luck.

In the future you might want to browse in private with **Incognito** mode.