# Google Chrome does not delete my browsing history

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, history

I have EXACTLY the same problem as Derfder had. I tried all proposals and advices mentioned below but nothing works. After deleting ALL browsing history, the urls are still in the autosuggestion.

[Google Chrome doesn't delete my browsing history correctly](https://superuser.com/questions/610523/google-chrome-doesnt-delete-my-browsing-history-correctly)

Comment: Yes; If you read all the answers it says Chrome will still autofill what it believes you want, but it won't be based on your history.

Answer (score 0):

#### Google Chrome does not delete my browsing history

You need to disable the Prediction Service.

---

#### Get predictions in the address bar

> When you type in the address bar, Google Chrome can use a prediction service to help you complete the web addresses and search terms that you're entering. For example, typing new york in the address bar could bring up http://www.nytimes.com as a predicted site or [ new york city ] as a predicted search.

---

#### Disable the Prediction Service

> The prediction service is typically turned on by default. Follow the
> steps below to turn it off.
>
> - Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
> - Select Settings.
> - Click Show advanced settings.
> - In the "Privacy" section, deselect the "Use a prediction service to help complete searches and URLs typed in the address bar" checkbox.
>
> Keep in mind that the address bar shows matches from your browsing
> history, in addition to predictions.
>
> **If you don't want to see matches
> from your browsing history, [clear your browsing history](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/answer.py?answer=95537).**

Source [Get predictions in the address bar](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95656?hl=en)